# Exporting and importing a view from a custom module

Tags: views, importing-exporting

From my understanding you can export your views and content types to a module so that you can replicate the view and content type on another server. My question is, if I export the view to a module and write the views api in my module, will the view/content type show up under the structure menu, if so would any changes made there be reflected back in the code of the module, or does this require another export and saving the output back into the module code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content types and Views are 2 different things. It's your job as a module developer to keep the two in sync over time.

Some modules can help with this such as the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module, if you dont want to track all this by hand every time.